# custom Kubernetes HPA algorithm

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to horizontally autoscale a workload not only by custom metrics but also by algorithm that differs from algorithm described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#algorithm-details)

1/ is that possible?

2/ if it is not, and assuming i don't mind creating a container that does the autoscaling for me instead of HPA, what API should i call to do the equivalent of `kubectl scale deployments/<name> --replicas=<newDesired>` ?

here's the use-case:

1/ the workload consumes a single request from a queue, handles them, when done removes the item it handled, and consumes the next message.

2/ when there's more than 0 messages ready - I'd like to scale up to the number of messages ready (or max scale if it is larger).
when there's 0 messages being processed - i'd like to scale down to 0.

getting the messages ready/ messages being processed to metrics server is not an issue.

getting HPA to scale by "messages ready" is not an issue either.

but...

HPA algorithm scales gradually... 
when i place 10 items in queue - it first to 4, then to 8 then to 10.

it also scales down gradually, and when it scales down it can terminate a pod that was processing - thus increasing the "ready" and causing a scale-up.

a node.js code that i would have run had i known the api to call (intead of HPA):

```
    let desiredToSet = 0;
    if (!readyMessages && !processingMessages) {
      //if we have nothing in queue and all workers completed their work - we can scale down to minimum
      //we like it better than reducing slowly as this way we are not risking killing a worker that's working
      desiredToSet = config.minDesired;
    }
    else {
      //messages ready in the queue, increase number of workers up to max allowed
      desiredToSet = Math.max(Math.min(readyMessages + processingMessages, config.maxDesired), currentDeploymentReplicas);
    }
    //no point in sending a request to change, if nothing changed
    if (desiredToSet !== currentDeploymentReplicas) {
      <api to set desiredToSet of deployment to come here>;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I don't think it's possible. The HPA controller is built-into Kubernetes and I don't think its algorithm can be extended/replaced.

2) Yes, you can create a custom controller that does the job of the HPA with your own algorithm. To scale the Deployment up and down through the Kubernetes API, you [manipulate the Scale sub-resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#replace-scale-deployment-v1-apps) of the Deployment.

Concretely, to scale the Deployment to a new number of replicas, you make the following request:

```
PUT /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}/scale
```

With a [Scale](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#scale-v1-autoscaling) resource (containing the desired replica count) as a body argument, as described in the API reference.

Comment: sounds like what i was loooking for :)

thanks.

I was thinking of using readNamespacedDeploymentScale() and replaceNamespacedDeploymentScale() from https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript rather than reinvent the wheel with pure http requests. 
any tips/ things i should be aware of when doing that?

Comment: Sure, you should use the corresponding functions of the Kubernetes client library if it provides any. I think there's nothing special to consider, the functions just make the HTTP requests under the hood. Maybe consider that the original HPA algorithm ensures minimum delays between scaling operations to prevent "thrashing", i.e. too frequent opposing scaling operations, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-cooldown-delay

Comment: final note:
i wound up using the kubernetes-client javascript lib mentioned above, as it saved a lot of code fo setting up a request to kubernetes.default that will not be thrown for bad creds etc.
an important note to those using this in rbac enabled cluster - don't forget to add a role, serviceAccount, roleBinding, and to associate your deployment with the service account.